# Start activity at top of navigation stack in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am implementing the solution for `TabActivity` with activities in the `TabHost` as described at http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html. I realize this is sub-optimal but I am already down this road pretty far and have only one remaining hiccup. I have a need to pop to the top of the stack that I am managing (using a list of `String` for activity ID) and I know that I can get this activity using:

```
Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(0));
```

However, I do not know of a method for "showing" `current`.

I know that I can do this:

```
Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(1))
current.finish();
```

And this will have the desired result in the case of there being at least two activities on the stack. However, when there is only one, it fails very badly with an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

How can I "show" a given activity?

Comment: check size first `mIdList.size()`

Comment: I know, but what do I do when `size()` == 1?

Comment: mIdList.get(0) when its size 1.
1 element, and position always starts at index 0 with item nr 1

Comment: if size is 1 then only one activity in stack and you are trying to second...using `mIdList.get(1)` so use `mIdList.get(0)` when size is 1

Comment: I understand, but I want to show activity 0 always. Typically, I will do `activity.finish()` to get the `n-1` activity, but if `n` is 1, then the program will just close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to start an activity which is always at the top in Activity Stack:

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processes1 = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = processes1.get(0).topActivity;
String classname =processes1.get(0).topActivity.getClassName(); 
String packagename = processes1.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
if(classname.equalsIgnoreCase("com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME..YOURACTIVITY_NAME"))
    {
        Intent intent24 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
        Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
        "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME..YOURACTIVITY_NAME").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
        "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME..YOURACTIVITY_NAME"));
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent24);
    }
    else
    {
     //DONE SOMETHING HERE...
    }
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer, because I did something similar (used `Intent`) but not as complicated... and possibly wrong... but it seems to work. `        Intent firstIntent = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(0)).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(mIdList.get(0), firstIntent);
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());`

Comment: +1 for telling me new way to start background activity but sure your code will work for think only if you are using this code in an  activity but my code work from both service and activity or from broadcast receiver bez i have tested it.but friend will get answer.